# My Website have Sudden increase in website load time on pingdom

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have some WordPress websites and from last few days there is sudden increase in website load-time according to Pingdom tool. It was b/w 2 to 3 sec before 2 June 2014, but now its 9 to 10 sec on Pingdom.

We are unable to find any change in code or scripts. It seems there is any problem with server end, but hosting team also confirmed that they have no problem with hosting server.

So I am unable to reach the root of problem. I will appreciate any kind of help, if anyone can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are unable to find any change in code or scripts. It seems there is
>   any problem with server end, but hosting team also confirmed that they
>   have no problem with hosting server.

It could be a simple growth in traffic. Or your database of content supporting your site is growing to the point that basic queries for content slow down the site.

The best solution to a question this broad is to install a tool like [`WordPress Super Cache`](http://ocaoimh.ie/wp-super-cache/) to speed up overall performance on your WordPress site. It works quite well by generating static content pages based on WordPress content so each time someone visits your site, PHP & MySQL do not have to strain to generate content.  As explained on the official [`WordPress Super Cache`](http://ocaoimh.ie/wp-super-cache/) site:

> WP Super Cache is a static caching plugin for WordPress. It generates
>   html files that are served directly by Apache without processing
>   comparatively heavy PHP scripts. By using this plugin you will speed
>   up your WordPress blog significantly.
>
> […]
>
> WP Super Cache gets around that. When it is installed, html files are
>   generated and they are served without ever invoking a single line of
>   PHP. How fast can your site serve graphic files? That’s (almost) as
>   fast it will be able to serve these cached files. If your site is
>   struggling to cope with the daily number of visitors, or if your site
>   appears on Digg.com, Slashdot or any other popular site then this
>   plugin is for you.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion. i am also facing the problem, that if any user surf my website for 1-2 mins continuously, then that particular user get blocked for website and after 10-15 min he unable to access website.
the same problem i am also facing